# Good Textbook on Boundary Integral Equation or Boundary Element Methods Using Mathematica

Tags: numerical-integration, documentation, reference-request

Is there a good textbook out there that treats Boundary Integral Equations or Boundary Element Methods Using Mathematica? I have scouted around a bit and could not find a good textbook that treats such numerical methods with examples.

Any suggestions on relevant text or lecture notes would be appreciated.